# How to use FIO to test a FUSE filesystem?

Tags: linux, performance, benchmarking, fuse

I'm using fio to test the performance of fuse filesystem using this commandline:

```
fio -filename=/User/mbl/fusefs -direct=1 -iodepth 1 -thread -rw=write -ioengine=psync -bs=16k -size=1G -numjobs=30 -runtime=1000 -group_reporting -name=mytest
```

in which /User/mbl/fusefs is the path of my fuse filesystem. However, I met this error:

```
fio: pid=0, err=21/file:filesetup.c:137, func=unlink, error=Is a directory
```

I searched on the internet and they said that fio can only test a block_device, such as --filename=/dev/$block_device, but I don't know how to make a fuse filesystem to be a block_device. Is there any way?

Comment: Perhaps what is needed is the `directory` param rather than `filename`? It might just work without any of the two if you just `cd` into your mount.

Comment: This cant work, `directory` param is to set the Prefix of `filename` param...

Answer (score 0):

instead of filename `-filename=/User/mbl/fusefs` use `--directory=/User/mbl/fusefs`